# Jupyter Notebook Dashboard: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dashboards_bundlers'

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, dashboard

I'm running notebook 5.0.0 on Python 3.6.1 in an Anaconda environment.

After successfully installing jupyter-dashboards-bundlers in my environment and entering (according to instructions at https://github.com/jupyter-incubator/dashboards_bundlers):

jupyter bundlerextension enable --sys-prefix --py dashboards_bundlers

I receive error:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dashboards_bundlers'

If I run:

jupyter bundlerextension list

It shows no known bundlerextensions.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this by adding an --ignore-install flag to the pip command, as suggested in the following thread about a different module with the same issue:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6548

Thank you.